# How to verify digital signature of SOAP call?

Tags: soap, cxf, xml-signature

I wrote an interceptor in Apache CXF and get a SoapMessage. How do I get the raw XML from the SOAP message without changing the data to hurt the verification of the digital signature?

I refer to org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage:

```
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage;
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.AbstractSoapInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.EndpointSelectionInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.Phase;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
public class XmlSignatureVerifyInInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(XmlSignatureVerifyInInterceptor.class);

    public XmlSignatureVerifyInInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.READ);
        log.entry();
        addAfter(ReadHeadersInterceptor.class.getName());
        addAfter(EndpointSelectionInterceptor.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage soapMessage) throws Fault {
        log.entry(soapMessage);
    }

}
```

Cheers and thank you in advance!

Fireball

Answer (score 0):

If you are refering a javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage, and you want a String result of XML, use ByteArrayOutputStream:

```
SOAPMessage message;
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
String msg = "";
try {
    message.writeTo(out);
    msg = out.toString("UTF-8");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I use UTF-8 as encoding, you can change it to any others.